# Android - Volley request throws ECONNREFUSED when App is closed

Tags: android, econnrefused

I have an alarm manager that runs an `intentservice` which fetch data from a server every minute and then sends a notification. Problem is when the app is opened i can still get the data but if the app is closed it sends it throws `ECONNREFUSED`.

**VOLLEY ERROR:**

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:com.android.volley.NoConnectionError:
java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to samples.openweathermap.org/138.201.197.100 (port 443) AFTER 2500ms: isConnected failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
```

Testing in `Android 5.1.1`

**Main Activity:**

```
 private void scheduleAlarm() {
    Intent toastIntent= new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MyBroadcastReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent toastAlarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, toastIntent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    long startTime=System.currentTimeMillis(); //alarm starts immediately
    AlarmManager backupAlarmMgr=(AlarmManager)this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    backupAlarmMgr.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,startTime,1000*30,toastAlarmIntent); // alarm will repeat after every 15 minutes
}
```

**Broadcast Receiver:**

```
public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
   MyJobIntentService.enqueueWork(context,intent);
}}
```

**MyJobIntentService:**

```
public class MyJobIntentService extends JobIntentService {
private String status="";

public static void enqueueWork(Context context, Intent work) {
    enqueueWork(context, MyJobIntentService.class, 1000, work);
}

@Override
protected void onHandleWork(@NonNull Intent intent) {
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
    String url = "http://forsitefloodapp.xyz/Func/Func_GetFloodReportsBarangay";
    RequestFuture<JSONArray> future = RequestFuture.newFuture();
    JsonArrayRequest request = new JsonArrayRequest(url,future,future);
    requestQueue.add(request);

    try {
        JSONArray response = future.get(10, java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        int size = response.length();

        if(size==0){
            status="NO REPORTS";
        }
        else {
            status="REPORTS DETECTED";
        }

    } catch (InterruptedException e) { status="Interuppted";

    } catch (ExecutionException e) { status=e.toString();

    } catch (TimeoutException e) { status="Timeout";

    }
    Log.i("MyJobIntentService", "Completed service @ " + status);

    //Sends notification
}}
```

Comment: Sir,post the log errors....which android version you use??

Comment: I have updated the post to answer your questions.

Comment: check my answer if fit your needs mark it as correct...if you face any difficulties with the implementation let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`intentservice`  will not work as background service (app closed) from `api 21` and above ..if you just target `api 21` onwards use `JobScheduler API`...if you target `Api 14` onwards(Oreo or pre-Oreo) use `JobIntentService` as its the modernway.your alarm manager should trigger `broadcastreceiver` which start the service when the time is up. service will fetch the data and send notification for that.

Comment: I have change the `intentservice` to `JobIntentService` but it still throws the `ECONNREFUSED` error.

Comment: @ParralelUniverse try to check your internet service or use retrofit for that request..please if you find my answer usefull mark it as correct...ikonw it solved problem will happen in the future

Comment: It seems that the service's internet access get disabled when the app gets closed. Logcat:`I/MyJobIntentService: internet: false`

Comment: After further testing it seems that the internet gets available to the service when the phone's screen is off, if it is on the connection gets disabled.

Comment: @ParralelUniverse if the answer fit your needs mark it as correct

Comment: Fixed: My data settings was apparently blocking the app.