# How Instagram android app is Running NotifyService without killed by the system in android > 8 ?

Tags: android, service, android-8.0-oreo

i wanted to run a service in background for receiving notifications, most of the apps are not running the background services but my requirement pushes me to run a service without it being foreground with notification.
i found that Instagram is running a service for very long time without consuming
the battery. i need help.

Comment: The only people who can tell you how a specific app works are probably under NDA.  Ask about the behavior you want, rather than how the other app works.

Comment: sure ill update the requirement but thought it would be easier to refer to something that is doing it

Comment: your requirement is just service run in background to fetch data and send notification for that.??

Comment: yes but service is being killed by the system in android oreo or later

Comment: read my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/52019521/9130109